# How to reset the PC to a Pure Windows 11 Pro state?

Tags: windows-11, iso-image, reset, factory-defaults

When I reset my PC (and chose delete everything) it just reverts it back to the state I got it from the manufacturer with all the bloatware they installed (even though it's Windows 11 Pro).

Now that I have installed Windows 11 Pro from an ISO onto my PC, when I select reset my PC from the menu, when it restores, will it just be a pure Windows 11 Pro install or would it go back to the manufacturer's state?

If so how do I make a checkpoint so when I do "reset my PC" and remove all user files option it will revert back to the checkpoint (kind of like how the manufacturer set it up in the first place where resetting the PC just goes back to their initial state).

Comment: If you reformat and delete all partitions, then the new recovery partition will be the the Windows 11 you installed.  If you just reinstalled Windows with the existing partitions, then the recovery partition will be the original Manufacturer's partition.

Comment: “If so how do I make a checkpoint …” - The Windows image that existed on your system that you want to now backup, is permanently gone, since you installed Windows 11 from a default Microsoft Windows image.

Comment: Why do you want to backup the WIndows image that contain "bloatware from manufacture", software you clearly didn't want installed, since you performed a clean install of Windows directly from a baseline Windows image released by Microsoft?  There is nothing that was installed on that image that cannot be manually installed.

Comment: I think i worded my question wrong @Ramhound, after installing the pure windows 11 iso, i would like to make that the "restore point" so that when i do reset this pc it reverts to that, (kinda of like how it reverts to the manufacturer's image on resetting the pc while selecting delete all files).

Comment: @PHV - That already will happen.  You deleted the OEM manufacture's Windows image when you reinstalled Windows from a different Windows image.

Comment: @John if you want to post your comment as an answer, i will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reformat and delete all partitions, then the new recovery partition will be the the Windows 11 you installed.

If you just reinstalled Windows with the existing partitions, then the recovery partition will be the original Manufacturer's partition.

The first approach is often best as over time you will want your own install to be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

> Now that I have installed Windows 11 Pro from a ISO onto my PC, when I select reset my PC from the menu, when it restores will it just be a pure Windows 11 Pro install or would it go back to the manufacturer's state?

As always, it'll revert to the state of the respective **restore** point. If you installed it yourself from the standard installer it won't include any of the manufacturer's additional software, obviously.

"Reset my PC" always means reinstall Windows and selecting that option on a user installed Windows always recover the original installation without any additional software including the ones you may have installed *a posteriori*.

You may consider using restore points instead. So:

> how do i make a checkpoint

This hasn't changed for Windows 11. [Instructions from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-system-restore-point-77e02e2a-3298-c869-9974-ef5658ea3be9) are the same as they ever were. Easy way is:

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type **Create a restore point**, and select it from the list of results.
2. On the **System Protection** tab in System Properties, select **Create**.
3. Type a description for the restore point, and then select **Create > OK**.

Comment: I think you're confusing System Restore with Reset This PC.

Comment: @gronostaj Not quite. Maybe the OP is but I answered both questions.

Comment: Well, yes, they have used the word "restore" once, but in its generic meaning, not referencing System Restore. The question is clearly about Reset This PC.

Comment: @gronostaj Edited to add additional information to clarify the difference.

Comment: Yep, when i said "restore point" i meant in the general, not the System Restore point feature within windows itself where it goes back to that *without* doing a clean reinstall.

Comment: So, again, it'll always reinstall exactly as it did when you actually installed it. OEM installations, OTOH, may include 1) additional drivers and 2) additional software at the discretion of the manufacturer. Nothing if that applies to the installation you did yourself using the standard installer as provided by Microsoft. Hence why in the edit I specifically mentioned that you should consider using restore points instead.